# Git - GitHub account and Atlassian Stash account on a PC

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

There are a lot of Questions on here and the web about Multiple "GitHub" accounts...

But I have an issue where I need to use two Git solutions;

- I need to be working on a GitHub account, already setup and working.
- We are migrating across to Atlassian Stash, another Git provider, so for the time being I need to work on both.

Forgive my ignorance as a WebDev, I try to stay away from system settings and command prompt.

But as I understand it, "Git" not "GitHub" is managed locally with global credentials and configurations.

So running these commands will bump me off of GitHub;
git config --global user.name "Will Hancock"
git config --global user.email "will.hancock@webtekkers.com"

Here's an Idea... If I used the same email and same password on both would that work?!?
Like ONE Git credentials, then the repo is configured on a per repo basis?

Have I understood this correctly?!?

I am reluctant to "mess around" and have a play, as these are not my repo's and I need to be able to work today.

Comment: Both are different "git" service providers, ofcourse you can use the same commit name. I don't really get your question.

Comment: Two different providers... differnet credentials... I guess if I change it globally I can't use the other...

Comment: What do you mean by change it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the git repository remote connections. When cloning on github to your local machine the remote connection in your local git-repo is the "origin" remote. You need to point that to Stash instead of GitHub. Other than that you should be fine.

`git remote set-url origin "git://your.stash.repo.domain/yourproject.git"`

Help on git remote: http://gitref.org/remotes/#remote